# run shell command in series while updating the front-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, async.js

I am trying to build an online converter, and I'm facing an issue I can't solve.

Basically, what I'm trying to do, is simply to run these stuff **one after another**:

1. run one command-line operation (with *require('child_process').exec()*)
2. now that the command-line operation is done, update the front-end (with *io.emit()*)
3. now that the front-end has been updated, run another command-line operation (again with *require('child_process').exec()*).
4. now that the 2nd command-line operation is done, update the front-end, again with io.emit().
5. and so on

Each front-end update and each command-line takes between 2 to 10 seconds, and I **need** to wait for one to finish before doing the next one. I can't start updating my front-end while running the next command-line in the background. I don't want that. I want each thing to run, wait for it to finish, and then run the next thing.

So, my **server-side** code looks like that:

```
async.series([
    function (callback) {
      client.join(room_, callback);
    },
    function (callback) {
      io.to(room_).emit('step0');
    },
    function (callback) {
      var command_1 = require('child_process').exec('some shell commands');
    },
    function (callback) {
      io.to(room_).emit('step1');
    },
    function (callback) {
      var command_2 = require('child_process').exec('some other shell commands');
    },
    function (callback) {
      io.to(room_).emit('step2');
    }
  ],
function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

And my client-side code looks like that:

```
socket.on('step0', function(data){
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function(i){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $(".uk-progress").css('width', i + '%');
        $(".uk-progress").text(i + '%');
    }, 100 * i)
   })(i);
  }
});

socket.on('step1', function(data){
  for(var i = 10; i < 30; i++) {
    (function(i){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $(".uk-progress").css('width', i + '%');
        $(".uk-progress").text(i + '%');
    }, 1000 * i)
   })(i);
  }
});

socket.on('step2', function(data){
  for(var i = 30; i < 101; i++) {
    (function(i){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $(".uk-progress").css('width', i + '%');
        $(".uk-progress").text(i + '%');
    }, 100 * i)
   })(i);
  }
});
```

and changing in my server-side

```
io.to(room_).emit('step0');
```

to

```
io.to(room_).emit('step0', callback);
```

gives me this error: `Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting`. 
If I try `io.to(room_).emit('step0', null, callback);` it doesn't work either and give me the same error.

Comment: The error means that broadcasting (calling `to(room).emit()`) doesn't accept a callback function as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can make it so that it runs the `.emit()` and **then** it runs what's left? If I simply do `io.to(room_).emit('step0');` it stops completely without running all the other functions.